# Completely Load XML Before Displaying Div

Tags: xml, html, hide, onload

I have a div that contains some data read from an XML file.

The problem is that the div flashes the "placeholders" before displaying the XML data. Here's the code:

```
<div id="Scoreboard">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr spry:detailregion="dsScores" spry:repeat="dsScores">
    <td>
      <table class="game" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="info" colspan="2">{dsScores::sport} - {dsScores::date}</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td class="name">{dsScores::awayName}</td>
            <td class="score">{dsScores::awayScore}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="name">{dsScores::homeName}</td>
            <td class="score">{dsScores::homeScore}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

So the visitor sees that stuff in the brackets for a split second before the XML populates the tables with the team names and scores. My question is, how do you hide the Scoreboard div until the XML file is completely loaded so that the visitor never sees the placeholders?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are populating the values using JavaScript, you could hide the outer div:

```
<div id="Scoreboard" style="display:none;">
```

Then simply run this after updating the cells with your data:

```
document.getElementById('Scoreboard').style.display = '';
```

Comment: Thanks, cdhowie. I had put this after the div:

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
window.onload = hideshowLayer;
function hideshowLayer() { 
document.getElementById("Scoreboard").style.display = "block"; 
}
</script>

Comment: Note that you don't need to explicitly set the display style to block -- if you set it to nothing, it will take the CSS-default value of block anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to not hit Enter when doing a comment. But the above didn't work, so exactly where should it go? Is there any way to put it in the XML file? That seems like a foolproof place to make it work.

Comment: I don't know how this "XML file" is being processed, so I can't really help you unless you provide more details.  You would need to show the div after the data update is complete.

Comment: I have a script in the head that calls scoreboard.xml:                         <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var dsScores = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("/assets/scoreboard.xml", "scores/game", {useCache: false});
</script>

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Spry to help you further, but all I can say is to look for a mechanism that allows you to execute a function after all of the data in the document has been updated, and shove the code to show the div there.